# Event Pattern for creating a rule/trigger (CloudWatch-Lambda) when AWS Step Function `ExecutionsFailed`

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, aws-step-functions

When my AWS Step Functions' State Machine fails `ExecutionsFailed` , I'd like to trigger a lambda function in response to it.

Seems that you have to create a rule on CloudWatch; but I couldn't find description on how to do that (in particular how the Event Patterns supposed to look like).

p.s. in my case it happens due to exceeding 25,000 history limit (so not quite so easy to handle within state machine; without having to add loop counters etc.; so I'd prefer for it to fail; and then handle it via lambda)

Answer (score 0):

Current workaround is to create a `cron` rule for a scheduled event on a cloudwatch; and the check the state machine; and in case it is failed; handle it.